# Where to get logs of "system preferences" > "profile" importation?

Tags: apple-configurator

I have created a VPN profile with Apple Configurator 2, I'm now trying to import it via System Preferences > Profiles, but I'm getting the unsuccessful message below without details. Where can I see error logs ?

[image]

Comment: For those who don't read French, here's a translation of the text in the error box: "Failed to install profile." "The "VPN Service" payload could not be installed. The server could not be created."